# New command without 3 argument brackets

Tags: macros

I would like to achieve the result of using the command `\scell{111}` and have the resultant output be `$1\times 1\times 1$` so that it can look like 1x1x1 but with the x being a \times sign.

I wrote the basic command `\newcommand{\scell}[3]{${#1}\times {#2}\times {#3}$}` which obviously has to be input as `\scell{1}{1}{1}`. There are always 3 numerical single digit arguments, is there a way to make the command work by inputting simply `\scell{111}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the argument to a three argument macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\scell}[1]{\doscell#1}
\newcommand{\doscell}[3]{$#1\times#2\times#3$}

\begin{document}

\scell{111}

\scell{1{29}3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a generalization:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\scell}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } { #1 }
  $\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \times }$
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\scell{111}

\scell{1{29}3}

\scell{3}

\scell{12}

\scell{12345}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With your existing definition you could use

```
\scell 1 1 1
```

or even

```
\scell111
```

In general `{}` may be omitted for single token arguments.

Comment: Oh I did not know this, thank you for sharing

Comment: I like to learn something new every day. Today, it was this.